# Jboss EAP AMQ119032: User does not have permission CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE on address

Tags: java, jboss, redhat, application-server, jboss-eap-7

I have a problem whit the error code AMQ119032: User does not have permission CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE on address, my code configuration it's `

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="mq" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="mq" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="mq"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="mq">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-topic name="myTopic" entries="topic/Myjava:jboss/exported/jms/topic/My"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

`

**What should be the proper role for me to post to the queue?**

Comment: What is the role of the suer you are using to connect to the broker ? He must have the 'guest' role as per your configuration

Comment: the rol is guest